# Why can't I run a oVirt Hosted Engine on VMware?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, vmware, operating-systems, vmware-workstation

I have VMware Pro and I just want to have a play around with oVirt. The installation was successful but when I go to the control panel and try to create a `Hosted Engine` it loads for a bit then says `Hardware virtualization is not supported on this host!`

I am running oVirt Node 4.3.8 and VMWare version 15.5.1

My VMware VM configuration is:

Memory: 4GB
Cores: 2
Storage: 50GB
Network: Bridged Connection

Images: [Web Interface Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlzIi.png) [VMware VM Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MkyVA.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Hardware virtualization is not supported on this host"  Does your host machine support Hardware Virtualization?  That is when I see this message.

Comment: Assuming you've enabled hardware virtualization on the host, you need to pass this through to the VM.  Following a "how to run hyper-v" in VMware guide should get you want you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all I had to do was, go into the setting of my VM in VMware and click on Settings and then click on Processors and under Virtualisation Engine, enable Virtualise Intel VT-x/EPT or AMD-V/RVI. Then it should work. Thanks for all your answers and comments but I found the answer a couple of days ago. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to virtualisation being disabled in the BIOS of the device.
I would first suggest checking by opening CMD and entering `systeminfo`
Once the results have been returned, check the bottom for "Hyper-V Requirements:", and confirm that next to `Virtualisation Enabled In Firmware:` it says `Yes`.

Should it say `No`, find your key to enter BIOS by searching "device model" + BIOS and shutdown your device.
Once booted into BIOS by pressing the BIOS key on startup, look around for any settings referring to virtualisation, e.g Intel Virtual Technology, AMD-V, Hyper-V or VT-X and enable them.